# refresh iframe on checkbox in timer

Tags: javascript, iframe, checkbox, timer, src

i have some checkboxes which i want to execute some code each second, the code inside the timer, which is inside of the if checked == true, it sets the src to be the same which i want it to refresh the iframe getting the new content on the iframe's website, the checkboxes are for different timers to reset the iframe, can u see whats stopping it executing, the code below;

```
if (document.getElementById("1").checked == true) {
  

setTimeout(function () {
  f.src = f.src;
    }, 100);
  }
  if (document.getElementById("2").checked == true) {
  

  setTimeout(function () {
    f.src = f.src;

      }, 5000);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to use `ifrmae.contentWindow.location.reload()` to reload the `iframe`.

```
if (document.getElementById("1").checked) {
  

setTimeout(function () {
  f.contentWindow.location.reload()
    }, 100);
  }

  if (document.getElementById("2").checked ) {
  

  setTimeout(function () {
    f.contentWindow.location.reload()
      }, 5000);
    }
```

Comment: ok i will change my code tysm!

Comment: @adamlewis, it seems no problem with your `settimeout`, since i don't have the full code, I don't know if it works. Tell me if it works!

Comment: yes it does ty!

Comment: i cant it wont let me accept it

Comment: @adamlewis, You can accept one answer (if it helps you) by click on big gray check button on its left side. If you wish you can add +10 points to any author of any good answer by click upper gray triangle. Thanks!

Comment: ok ive done it now sorry